# Symbols in Rich Text Field

Tags: tridion

What is the appropriate way to get symbols to publish correctly in a Rich Text  field.  For example, We are trying to the the registered trade mark symbol to show, but it always ends up with an extra Â in front of it, like this: .Â®.

WE tried &#174, but that gives the same result.  This sounds like a code page issue, but everything appers to be UTF-8?  Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of tridion are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be an encoding issue.  When you say "everything appears to be UTF-8", is the encoding set on your page declaration?  There are several other places to check for this.  Have a look through Elena's post about how to resolve encoding issues:  http://elenaserghie.blogspot.ca/2012/01/7-clues-to-solve-character-encoding.html

Comment: ok, I looked through that & I'll modify my question a bit.    Why can't I get the RTF to output &#174 ?  It keeps translating  &#174  to ®.  Is that the default XSLT filter doing that ?

Comment: What does your Content Delivery look like, are you using oData, CWA, etc?

Comment: In your Web application server, ensure that your Java Virtual Machine (JVM) is called with the correct file encoding by setting the file.encoding property.

Comment: There's also the Code Page setting on Publication Targets that you might want to check.